# How to perform refresh and not forced refresh on Firefox

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a website that requires NTLM authentication, so I have created a FireFox profile:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.SetPreference("network.http.phishy-userpass-length", 255);
profile.SetPreference("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", uri.Host);
profile.SetPreference("network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris", uri.Host);
profile.SetPreference("network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris", uri.Host);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Then I navigate to page with `GoToUrl` method which goes fine, but when I call `Refresh` - authentication popup comes up. Googling around [I found](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=318253#c128) that it occurs if call "forced refresh", like "Ctrl + F5" and indeed it does, even when do it manually. So, the question is how to perform a plain refresh and not forced refresh?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a way to test if this is going to "force" refresh, but you could try refreshing directly in JS. ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.location.reload()");

Comment: I had to use `IJavaScriptExecutor` as I'm in C#, but it did work, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

YOu have refresh as part of the webdriver API:

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
```